# php - How do I extract capitalised words from a string

Tags: php

Take this string:

```
Israel agrees to significant easing of Gaza blockade
```

I want to return the capitalised words, separated by a comma, like this:

```
Israel,Gaza
```

I imagine it must be possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Also works for the sentence `Gaza agrees to ease missile attacks, tunnel attacks and terrorism on civilians in Israel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code as suggested by @Patrick Daryll Glandien.

```
$stringArray = explode(" ", $string);
foreach($stringArray as $word){
  if($word[0] == strtoupper($word[0])){
    $capitalizedWords[] = $word;
  }
}
$capitalizedWords = join(",", $capitalizedWords);
//$capitalizedWords = implode(",", $capitalizedWords);
```

Comment: Alternately, you can also do `ucwords($word) == $word`.

Answer (score 9):

Split the string into it's words with [explode(' ')](http://us.php.net/explode), iterate through the words and check if the word is capitalized by checking if it's first letter (`$str[0]`) is the same as its uppercase variant (`strtoupper($str[0])`). You can fill an array with the results and then [join(',')](http://us.php.net/join) it

Comment: Nice. You might have to add something else to strip punctuation marks from the capitalized letters ==> "In the country of France, people it French frogs." returns "France,, French" - not sure if this is what's supposed to happen from the original post. Also, you can cut off leading and trailing whitespace after explode in order to deal with multiple spaces between words.

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_match_all()`:

```
preg_match_all('/[A-Z]+[\w]*/', $str, $matches);
```

If you need to work with non-English or accent characters, then use:

```
preg_match_all('/\p{L}*\p{Lu}+\p{L}*/', $str, $matches);
```

Which should also work for words where the first letter isn't capitalized, but a subsequent letter is as is customary in some languages/words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression. Something like the following should get your close:

```
<?php

$str = 'Israel agrees to significant easing of Gaza blockade';

preg_match_all('/([A-Z]{1}\w+)[^\w]*/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

Edit: My regex was way off.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'Israel agrees to significant easing of Gaza blockade';
$result = array();
$tok = strtok($str, ' ');
do {
    if($tok == ucfirst($tok))
        $result[] = $tok;
}
while(($tok = strtok(' ')) !== false);
```

Answer (score -4):

here is some code:

```
$arr = explode($words, ' ');

for ($word as $words){
    if($word[0] == strtoupper($word[0]){
        $newarr[] = $word;

print join(', ', $newarr);
```

Comment: 1. Poor formatting 2. Syntax errors 3. Inconsistent variable naming

Comment: `$arr` is the array that should be used in the loop. Your explode arguments are backwards, you use the wrong variable in the loop which as per my earlier comment should be a `foreach` not `for` loop. But I can see what you were getting at. See Babiker's answer above.